# Unable to merge rasters that do not have unique ID values but DO have other unique attribute values

Tags: merge, raster, terra

I am attempting to merge many rasters together by a specific attribute (i.e., land cover) and NOT by the primary key index (i.e., OID) since the OID values are not unique to specific land covers among different rasters. When I attempt to merge rasters that have different amounts of land covers, only the first raster's values will be used. Furthermore, if the ID values align with different land covers, one raster's land cover value changes in the new merged raster. I have provided some example code and would appreciate any help, thanks!

**Code Sample**

```
library(terra)
set.seed(0)
rast1 <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(rast1) <- sample(3, ncell(rast1), replace=TRUE)
d1 <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("conifer", "water", "barren"), 
                  letters=letters[1:3])
levels(rast1) <- d1

rast2 <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(rast2) <- sample(4, ncell(rast2), replace=TRUE)
d2 <- data.frame(id=1:4, cover=c("conifer", "water", "agriculture","barren"), 
                 letters=c("a","b","d","c"))
levels(rast2) <- d2

#Now try to merge rasters
Merge <- merge(rast1, rast2)
```

Issue: Merged raster only includes "cover" category from first raster input, and in the case with my data, non-unique ids are classified incorrectly into a different group. Here it would be that rast2's "agriculture" class is classified as "barren."

I have tried changing the raster levels manually, but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bit complex and perhaps "terra" should do that automatically. But for now you could do this with these two rasters

```
cat1 <- cats(r1)[[1]]
cat2 <- cats(r2)[[1]]

m <- match(cat1$cover, cat2$cover)
rc <- cbind(cat1$id, cat2$id[m])
r1c <- classify(r1, rc)
levels(r1c) <- levels(r2)

r12 <- merge(r1c, r2)
```

And if you have many rasters you may be able to use a loop like this.
`r2` is the most complete raster that we use as template.

```
x <- list(r2, r1)
mcat <- cats(r2)[[1]]

for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    r <- x[[i]]
    xcat <- cats(r)[[1]]
    m <- match(xcat$cover, mcat$cover)
    rc <- cbind(xcat$id, mcat$id[m])
    r <- classify(r, rc)
    levels(r) <- mcat
    x[[i]] <- r
}

s <- sprc(x)
m <- merge(s)
```

Comment: Hi Robert! Thank you so much for taking the time to work on this! I am now getting an issue where the raster with fewer levels - which also has a category not in raster 2, is being omitted. I should have set up the example as follows, instead of how I previously did.

Comment: rast1 <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(rast1) <- sample(3, ncell(rast1), replace=TRUE)
d1 <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("conifer", "grass", "barren"), 
                  letters=c("a","e","c"))
levels(rast1) <- d1

Comment: I realized I made an error when using the cbind function. I did not use the correct column name. Once I fixed that, it worked! Thank you so much for your help! I am sorry for the confusion.